# Jquery Datables delete and add new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

Issue:

If I delete some rows and add a new row after, the rows I deleted come back.

If I add 1 row and delete this one, after I add another row, inserts 2 instead just 1

so what I trying to archive is:

row deleted is deleted not back.

if I add new row added just 1, does not matter if i deleted a row before or not.

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>order</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<button id="addRow">Add New Row</button>
<table id="newRow">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Line 2
        <input type="hidden" value="2" /> </td>
      <td>DVap
        <input type="hidden" value="DVap" /> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="22" /> </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
    dt.fnDestroy();

  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQzyuEGndu?indent=2';
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      ajax: url,
      rowReorder: {
        dataSrc: 'order',
      },
      columns: [{
        data: 'order'
      }, {
        data: 'place'
      }, {
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        data: 'delete'
      }],
      "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
        $("i.fa.fa-minus-square").click(function(event) {
          $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
      }
    });
    // add row
    $('#addRow').click(function() {
      //t.row.add( [1,2,3] ).draw();
      var rowHtml = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML
      console.log(rowHtml);
      table.row.add($(rowHtml)).draw();
    });
  });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5L2qy092/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use DataTables api to remove/delete rows, other wise DataTables cant know whats actually deleted.

also you need to use `initComplete` instead, since `fnDrawCallback` fires every time table draws, so you don't want to add `click event` handler every time

```
 "initComplete": function(oSettings) {
    $("i.fa.fa-minus-square").click(function(event) {
      table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).remove().draw();
    });
  }
```

working [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/31/)

EDIT

use jquery `delegate click` for dynamically added rows

```
 "initComplete": function(oSettings) {
    $(this).on("click", "i.fa.fa-minus-square", function(event) {
      table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).remove().draw();
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this it is what i am looking for, sorry but i need be able to delete the rows a added too will be possible?: see my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5L2qy092/3/

Comment: yes, you need to use `click delegate`. update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5L2qy092/4/